# How to combine data from 2 columns with values separated by a symbol?

Tags: excel, excel-formula, worksheet-function

Data in 1st column contains data types separated by '#' symbol:

```
Year#Storey#Area#Condition#Name
```

Data in 2nd column contains information corresponding to data types in 1st column also separated by '#' symbol:

```
2015#3#170#Renovated#John
```

I want to combine information from 1st and 2nd columns and get data in the following format:

```
Year - 2015
Storey - 3
Area - 170
Condition - Renovated
Name - John
```

To clarify I provide picture of what I want to get:
[image: height="50" width="50"]

Ho to implement it in Excel? What kind of formula I need to specify?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do this with a relatively simple User Defined Function.

```
Option Explicit
Function CombineCells(R1 As Range, R2 As Range, Optional Sep As String = "#")
    Dim V1 As Variant, V2 As Variant
    Dim I As Long

V1 = Split(R1, Sep)
V2 = Split(R2, Sep)

'Check that same number of items in each
If UBound(V1) <> UBound(V2) Then
    MsgBox Prompt:="Data Error" & vbLf & "Item Count different in the Two Cells", Title:="Input Error"
End If

For I = 0 To UBound(V1)
    V1(I) = V1(I) & " - " & V2(I)
Next I

CombineCells = Join(V1, vbLf)

End Function
```

To enter this User Defined Function (UDF), `alt-F11` opens the Visual Basic Editor.
Ensure your project is highlighted in the Project Explorer window.
Then, from the top menu, select `Insert/Module` and
paste the code below into the window that opens.

To use this User Defined Function (UDF), enter a formula like

```
=CombineCells(A2,B2)
```

in some cell.

Answer (score 2):

You can avoid all the headache to extract column data from a data line by creating a UDF in VBA.

To do this, create a VBA module in your workbook and place this code:

```
Function GETCOLUMNDATA(Cell As Range, ColumnNumber As Long, Delimeter As String) As String
    GETCOLUMNDATA = Split(Cell, Delimeter)(ColumnNumber - 1)
End Function
```

Then you can extract the data with ease, as shown:

Formula is shown in the formula bar.

[image]

Then for your desired format, just join them back accordingly.

[image]

Note: to put a linefeed in a cell, hit Alt+Enter